# adding an item to ul and maintiang sequence - jquery sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i have a two `ul` lists out of which one contains strings and the other contains numbers.now i should be able to place the string any where between the lists but the sequence of the number should be maintained.

```
   string                   

    1                 1
    2                 2
    3               string
    4                 3 
                      4

 initial state       final state
```

how to achieve this, when i make both the lists sortable users will be allowed to move the **numbers which shouldn't be allowed**. my implementation so far [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D5LbV/8/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the elements you don't want to allow to be dragged around. Here I added "noMove" as the class and then add them to the elements:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D5LbV/9/

```
$(function(){
    $(' .tree').sortable({
        connectWith :'.tree',
        cancel: '.noMove',
        start : function(){
        $('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').addClass(' glyphicon-chevron-down');
            $('ul.tree').fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
});
```